# Django Models.filefiled file dosent exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I wish to access the file i upload using models.FileField(), but its shows different path when i click on the link provided in the admin page. May i know what's the problem here?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Updated my code, but the url dosent seem corret. getting a 404 code error.

Comment: post your model and the settings where you have written the media root

Comment: did you set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT on your `settings.py` file?

Comment: @Exprator Updated my code with picture.

Comment: @Beomi Do you mind take a look on my settings and tell me whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to declare `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')`

and add them to the urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```